# Best way to convert a string like May 2nd 2017 to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have many records with a string like 'May 2nd 2017'.

What would be the best way to convert to datetime? I was hoping to do it directly in SQL Server...Otherwise I'll just have to loop the records with PHP...

Comment: More than one example please - for instance, are all of the dates of the form `<3 char month name> <ordinal number> <year>`? Or `<complete month name> <ordinal number> <year>`? Or are there other combinations you also have to deal with?

Comment: The long term and clean solution to this problem, is to store date values in a `date` (or `datetime`) column, not  as a  `varchar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the month is 3 characters like Aug vs. Augu**st**

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = 'May 2nd 2017'

Select try_convert(date,replace(replace(replace(replace(@S,'st',''),'nd',''),'rd',''),'th',''))
```

If Full month, just one more replace to correct August

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = 'August 2nd 2017'

Select try_convert(date,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@S,'st',''),'nd',''),'rd',''),'th',''),'u ',' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of server language setting when doing that. This would work in older versions too:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(20) ='May 2nd 2017';


SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
  LEFT(@v, 3)+
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  RIGHT(@v, LEN(@v)-3), 'st', ''), 'nd', ''), 'rd', ''), 'th', ''), 9);
```